# How to save images locally with node-fs from urls

Tags: node.js, save, cheerio

Node beginner here, can't seem to find a straightforward answer for this. 
Using cheerio I've grabbed some urls of images, that part is working fine, then I want to save those images to an `output` folder. I can grab the image url, but can't seem to figure out how to save the actual image locally. Not sure if I need to use `stream` or `https` or what. Here's what I have:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');
const fs = require("fs");

const myWebsite = 'https://www.loremipsum.com';

request(myWebsite, function (error, response, body) {

     let $ = cheerio.load(body);

     $('div').each(function(i, element){
          if($(this).css('background-image')){

              //get the image url from a div w a bg image style
              let pic = $(this).css('background-image').replace('url(','https:').replace(')','').replace(/\"/gi, "");

              filename = pic + '.png'
              //!!!WRITE filename TO output DIRECTORY HERE with node fs?!!!
              }
           }
        })
    });
```

if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may help you.

```
request.get('image url')
.on('error',function(err){
 console.log(err);
})
.on('response',function(response){
 if(response.statusCode == 200){
  console.log("successfully retreived image from url");
 }
})
.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('your destination folder path' + filename));
```

Comment: This worked!!! thank you so much. one small note is I think it should be .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('your destination folder path' + filename));